# Code to auto-ban new discord accounts is not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I created this bot, with the intention to ban an account if it's created within less than 2 days

So here's the code to ban new accounts

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
if (Date.now() - member.user.createdAt < 172800000) {
    member.ban({ reason: 'new account' })
}});
```

The bot is functional (I know that because I added a ping feature, and it responds to my messages in chat), but every time I create an alt account and join my server, it doesn't ban the account.

Bot permissions are ok, it has every single one. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are guild member intents enabled?

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is nothing just happening?

Comment: Enabling guild member intents worked, thanks